# Istio-proxy http2 stream dependency & priority handling

Tags: istio

I hope this is the right forum/category to ask this question, if no, request to please point me to correct.

I’m verifying HTTP/2 transfer (with-prior-knowledge i.e w/o upgrade) from one micro-service to another. Each service has an istio-proxy as a sidecar. When HTTP/2 traffic from pod1(microservice 1) is sent to pod2(microservice2), istio-proxy intercepts it and forwards the request to pod2.

Observation is that at client - pod1, when HTTP/2 transfer is initiated, it shows the stream priority and dependency in pcap towards istio-proxy, but not in the requests from istio-proxy to destination pod. PCAP was taken on client pod with ANY IP. The destination server/application is also not consistent with the stream dependency & priority handling, basically on multiple http/2 transfers the expectation of the server processing the streams is not consistent w.r.t the dependency & priority specified and hence the concern.

Basically, I'm not able to see the stream priority/dependency information being forwarded by istio-proxy, is there some configuration for same or may be I'm not checking it correctly.

Any pointers/comments would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is clarified [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!topic/envoy-users/xqV1a5o6zTI)

as of now its not supported at istio-proxy